# Facebook login without opening another window/popup

Tags: python, facebook

Is it possible for web application that is created by the same owner as facebook application to have access to facebook application without going through a explicit session opening exercise?
Most of the work is done on server side and I need to access facebook application directly from backend server. Each time the website loads I do not want user to go through the facebook connect experience as data to be displayed does not require his facebook profile/data access.

Let me know if its possible?

Although its not related to language, I would be grateful if help is provided keeping python in mind. Thx

Comment: What kind of data do you need to access from the facebook application?

Comment: Groups associated with user who has created the facebook app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The opening of a window for facebook auth is the way facebook set up their authentication for facebook connect.

I don't think they offer another way of authenticating users, and I doubt you'd be able to work-around/circumvent this method without breaking their terms of use

Sorry I don't have better news for you :/

Comment: I know , I was just wondering if it could be done or if there is an acceptable workaround. Anyways thx for your confirmation.